# Get certificate out of default keystore of WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, websphere-8, ws-security

I want to sign a SOAP message with a given certificate which is stored in the default keystore of my WebSphere Application Server (8.5.5).

I'm refusing to provide a keystore path since the WebSphere should already know which keystores it has. And I would have to provide each path for each stage in our environments, which is what I wanted to prevent.

My code looks like this to sign my message:

```
private void signEnvelope(final SOAPMessageContext context) {
    try {
        final Document doc = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getOwnerDocument();
        final WSSecHeader header = new WSSecHeader();
        final Crypto crypto = CryptoFactory.getInstance(getCryptoProperties());
        header.insertSecurityHeader(doc);

        final WSSecTimestamp timestamp = new WSSecTimestamp();
        timestamp.build(doc, header);

        final WSSConfig config = WSSConfig.getNewInstance();
        config.setWsiBSPCompliant(false);

        final WSSecSignature signature = new WSSecSignature(config);
        signature.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.BST_DIRECT_REFERENCE);
        signature.setUserInfo("certificateAlias", "keystorePassword");
        signature.setDigestAlgo(WSConstants.SHA256);
        signature.setSignatureAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
        signature.setParts(getSignatureParts());
        signature.setSigCanonicalization(WSConstants.C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
        signature.build(doc, crypto, header);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Cannot sign message", e);
    }
}

private Properties getCryptoProperties() {
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
    props.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "PKCS12");
    props.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file", "/home/wasadm/IBM/AppServer/profiles/server1/config/cells/mycell/nodes/mynode/key.p12");
    props.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias", "myAlias");
    props.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", "myKeystorePassword");
    return props;
}

private List<WSEncryptionPart> getSignatureParts() {
    final WSEncryptionPart[] parts = new WSEncryptionPart[] {
        new WSEncryptionPart(WSConstants.TIMESTAMP_TOKEN_LN, WSConstants.WSU_NS, "Element"),
        new WSEncryptionPart(WSConstants.ELEM_BODY, WSConstants.URI_SOAP11_ENV, "Element")
    };

    return new ArrayList<WSEncryptionPart>(Arrays.asList(parts));
}
```

So, is it possible to just use the default keystore of WebSphere without providing an explicit path to this keystore?

Comment: Not exactly what you've asked, but have you tried using CONFIG_ROOT system property: `System.getProperty("CONFIG_ROOT") + /cells/mycell/nodes/mynode/key.p12`?

Comment: That's at least a good direction to get to the desired path, so thanks for this idea! Unfortunately, it's only the half truth. Every stage has their own node and cell names. So, I would need also something like `CONFIG_NODE` and `CONFIG_CELL` to provide this in a flexible way. But the direction is infact not bad :)